# Moving nuxt 3 to JavaScript from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

When getting started with nuxt 3, it creates TypeScript project by default.
Is there a way to move to JavaScript?

I have tried:

1. Rename `nuxt.config.ts` to `nuxt.config.js`
2. delete `tsconfig.json`
3. add `jsconfig.json`

Contents of `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
};
```

contents of `package.json`

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxi dev",
    "build": "nuxi build",
    "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt3": "latest"
  }
}
```

Still the `.nuxt` folder creates TypeScript files

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to use TS, you can still write regular JS code inside of it. At the end, it will still generate `.mjs` files.

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately in the current `nuxt3` version (`3.0.0-27268729.5b8e10f`), there is no configuration to disable the output of those type declaration files.

While the generated `.d.ts` file are intended to help TypeScript developers, Nuxt does not require app source to be written in TypeScript. The `.d.ts` files should have no impact on your JavaScript development other than the slight delay in generating those files.

Answer (score 3):

You can add in file `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```